# How to show that $\|x-y\|^2 \geq \frac{\beta}{1 + \beta} \|z-y\|^2 - \beta \|z-x\|^2$, where $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta > 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I recently came across an inequality involving the squared norm of the differences of some vectors. Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta > 0$. Then we have $$\|x-y\|^2 \geq \frac{\beta}{1 + \beta} \|z-y\|^2 - \beta \|z-x\|^2.$$ I am having trouble showing this, even though I feel the solution is staring me in the face. I feel this generalizes following:
$$\|x-y\|^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}\|z-y\|^2-\|z-x\|^2.$$

In fact, the two inequalities coincide for $\beta=1$. The above inequality follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, however I can't figure out how to generalize that technique. I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about eliminating variables if possible. Let $z-x = a$ and $y-z = b$ and then $y-x = a+b$ and you will want to prove:
$$\|a+b\|^2\geq \dfrac{\beta}{1+\beta}\|b\|^2 - \beta\|a\|^2.$$

Since you know the proof of the simpler case, then you know it starts out by expanding and so:
$$LHS - RHS = \|a\|^2+2(a,b)+\|b\|^2 - \dfrac{\beta}{1+\beta}\|b\|^2 + \beta\|a\|^2 = $$
$$ = \left((1+\beta)\|a\|^2 + \dfrac{1}{1+\beta}\|b\|^2\right) + 2(a,b).$$

Do you see how to finish it now ?

Comment: Ah, thank you. The next step would be $=\|\sqrt{1+\beta}a\|^2+\|\sqrt{1-\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}} b \|^2 + 2(\sqrt{1+\beta}a,\sqrt{1-\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}}b)$, and from there we have $=\|\sqrt{1+\beta} a + \sqrt{1-\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}} b\|^2 \geq 0$. Sweet!